# Convert dB to linear without floating point operations

Tags: c

How to convert dB to linear using integers only?
Approximate solutions are acceptable.

Clarification: dB to linear conversion is obtained with the formula
P = 10*log10(P_dB)
The inverse is obtained with the formula:
P_dB = 10^(P/10)

When programming in C, these require floating-point operations.

The range of P_dB is limited and goes from -50 to 50, the type is integer.

Is there an accepted method to obtain these conversions using integer operations only?

Comment: db as in decibels ? have you tried/researched  anything ?

Comment: Please list the solutions you have already researched and rejected so that we don't have to retrace ground you've already covered.

Comment: Show your floating point calculation.  Also describe the full range of input and output values you are working with.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what specifically you're having trouble with? Are you unsure how to convert a measurement in dB to the represented quantity? Or do you know what conversion you want to perform and how, but aren't sure how to accomplish it without using floating point operations? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Also, are you using C or C++? Those are two different languages with different math utilities available.

Comment: Voting to close this question.  There has been no response to the comments, no further edits or clarification, and it almost reads like a homework question or a phrase one might supply to a search engine.

Comment: in general, you never need floats, you don't even need mul and div, all you ever need are integers, +, -. This is why Clive Sinclair was disappointed with ppl playing games on the speccy. He gave us the tool to land on the moon and we were just playing games on it.

Answer (score 0):

Plus becomes multiplication, minus division.
example:

```
10dB ~ 10
3db ~ 2
```

```
57dB = 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 - 3
10*10*10*10*10*10/2 = 500000;
```

You do not need any floats.

Comment: Isn't that `1.5` in the latter example a float?

Comment: An unnecessary one

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Indeed